# Is there a way to automatically replace a pattern in .java file on build-time?

Tags: java, netbeans, build, replace

I want to be able to replace specific pattern in .java files on build time. In fact, I just want to replace certain String value to represent build time. (And I also want to leave original source file intact). Is there a way to do it easily (apart from manual way)?
I'm using NetBeans as my IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We needed something similar for our product (embed build time, build computer & user name into the compiled application).

We used ant's `manifest` task to embed a manifest into the jar which contains the information we needed. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifest.html .

The manifest can easily be read from the JAR using tools. If you need the information in your software, you can read it programatically, or put it into a .properties files (generated at build) which you can read from the program.

Answer (score 8):

At best do not put this pattern in java file, but load it from resource, f.g. .properties file. 
Maven has resource filtering features, you can then use profiles to change particular resources, or copy resources from other locations. Ant given you also the opportunity to use various resources locations.
You can always copy another properties file manually. In all cases source java file is intact. The code runs from your IDE and you can change pattern not recompiling the code.

Comment: What does `f.g.` stand for?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about editing Java code. But if you use maven, there is way work this out. Make a properties file, make a util class that reads the properties file for you. Use this class in other classes where you want the properties to be replaced at build time.

Basically,

Create a config.properties that has

```
myprop1=${val1}
myprop2=${val2}
```

Write a maven pom.xml that has profiles and do this

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
      <id>local</id>
      <properties>
        <val1>localval1</val1>
        <val2>localval2</val2>
      </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <properties>
        <val1>prodval1</val1>
        <val2>prodval2</val2>
      </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Make a class that reads this config.properties. And use it to read dynamic data.

Build using mvn -Plocal clean install or mvn -Pprod clean install to values gets replaced in config.properties based on profile.

Hope this helps.

---

With ANT, you can do the same.  In ANT, you create multiple config files say, local.config.properties and prod.config.properties. At the build time, you can pass a parameter like 'local' or 'prod'.

Do resource copy where you copy appropriate file based by prepending the parameter to config.properties (thus copying local.config,properties ot prod.config,properties). And after copying to classpath, rename to config.properties

Answer (score 1):

I think Ant or Maven could be of assistance to you - do you use either of these to perform your build? I've not used Maven but have done something similar in Java.

Comment: I believe NetBeans uses Ant for building java projects. But how exactly I can do this replacement using Ant?

Comment: I think lechlukasz has given good advice below - externalise the item into a properties file, then update this file either automatically (Maven/Ant), or manually - if it's only specified in one place this will be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Ant "replace" task, here's an example:

```
<replace file="${src}/index.html" token="@@@" value="wombat"/>
```

replaces occurrences of the string "@@@" with the string "wombat", in the file ${src}/index.html.